# Use replace string to change image size on PHP feed

Tags: php, image, rss, str-replace

I want to create a feed for a several pinterest boards. Before I get down too deep, I see the images, but they are small.

Before, using yahoo pipes I was able to modify the source and change 236x with 736x in the image URL and recreated the feed. But now that the service is about to shut down, I want to find a different alternative. Tried several services, but none seem to do the replacement as I want.

I know the image is in the description, but can't figure out how to use str_replace to accomplish this.

Hope you can share some ideas, thank you.

I have this so far:

```
    <?php
    $rss = new DOMDocument(); 
$feed = array();
$urlArray = array(array('name' => 'Otaku', 'url' => 'https://www.pinterest.com/anizeen/otaku.rss'),
                  array('name' => 'How To',  'url' => 'https://www.pinterest.com/anizeen/how-to-draw-anime-manga.rss'),
                  array('name' => 'Upcoming',   'url' => 'https://www.pinterest.com/anizeen/upcoming-anime-attractions.rss'),
                  array('name' => 'Manga', 'url' => 'https://www.pinterest.com/anizeen/manga.rss')
                  );

foreach ($urlArray as $url) {
    $rss->load($url['url']);

    foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
        $item = array ( 
            'site'  => $url['name'],
            'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'desc'  => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link'  => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'date'  => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            );
        array_push($feed, $item);
    }
}

usort($feed, function($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($b['date']) - strtotime($a['date']);
});

$limit = 3;
echo '<ul>';
for ($x = 0; $x < $limit; $x++) {
    $site = $feed[$x]['site'];
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $desc = str_replace('/236x/', '/736x/', $desc);
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));

    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>'.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}
    ?>
```